# VPNC not working with mobile stick only in 14.04

Tags: networking, vpn, mobile-broadband, vpnc

I use VPNC (the command line client from the package vpnc) to connect with my institution. The configuration file looks like this

```
IPSec ID CiscoGroup
IPSec gateway xxx.xxx.xxx
IPSec secret XXXXXXXX
IKE Authmode psk
NAT Traversal Mode cisco-udp
Xauth username xxxxxxx
```

The VPN connection works like a breeze if I use my wireless interface. However, if I am connected to the internet using a UMTS stick ("Lidl stick"), it no longer does. The UMTS alone is working -- I can use it to connect to the internet. The vpnc client gets started with no apparent errors, so it can approach and talk to the gateway and establish a connection. However, the moment it goes into background, I loose all connectivity.

This is not a DNS problem -- using IPs does not help.

Interestingly, I can still ping one and only server -- the gateway. Nothing else.

Is this a known problem? Is there a solution?

Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, changing the NAT mode used to 'force-natt' allows the connection to proceed normally. I changed the relevant line in the config file:

```
NAT Traversal Mode force-natt
```

Why this does work, however, I do not know. Therefore, I do not consider this to be the complete answer.

Comment: Hi! Perhaps you have better information now? Can you add some more information?